# Uploading project to GitHub from Visual Studio 2010

Tags: visual-studio-2010, github

I have a GitHub account.

I have a Visual Studio 2010 with Git Extensions and Git Source Control provider installed.

I have created a clean project. How do I upload it to GitHub?

P.S. A tutorial on this particular topic would be fine.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

In order to upload a Visual Studio Project to GitHub one needs to perform a push operation in GitExtension commit dialog.

Basically syncing the project with GitHub server is called "push"ing in Git terminology.

In order to be able to push, one needs to do the following:

1. Create a local repository. This is covered in detail by both GitHub and GitExtensions manual.
2. Create a repository online from GitHub account. This is covered in detail by [GitHub help](http://help.github.com/create-a-repo/).
3. Map a local repository to an online one. This requires going to Manage Remotes dialog of GitExtensions (accessed via Git->Manage Remotes menu item in Visual Studio main menu) and saving a new instance of a remote repo.
4. Then, at commit, choose to "Commit & push", and point push to a remote repo created in step 3.

Answer (score 0):

Create a new repository in your github account. It will give you the step by step instructions for you.

Comment: Ok, I will check it out. So, there is no way to create a repository from within the VS2010 itself?

Comment: For getting started Git does not need any heavy tool support. You may start with installing msysgit for windows and then navigating to your project folder through command line and simply issue the command git init. In this way you can create a repository for your project and for uploading the project you may follow the github instructions

Comment: After I create a repository, there are not instructions on how to upload a Visual Studio solution to GitHub.

Comment: The problem is that Visual Studio is not a heavy tool - it's the main tool I use, and if I am unable to work with GitHub from it, than GitHub needs to add this kind of integration.

Comment: Git and github are very simple concepts (albeit powerful). I have used console to manage the visual studio projects. What you need is to grasp the basics. This tutorial may help. http://gitimmersion.com/index.html. Once you are familiar with the fundamentals you may move to your graphical tool.