# Git Source Control Provider

Tags: git, version-control, github, visual-studio-2012

I am using git source control provider with Visual Studio. It works fine, my question is more that I don't see anything in my repository on github except my readme. Is that normal behavior? Or should I be able to see all the solution and c# files as well?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You would see more file if you are pushing your local Visual Studio project/solution to GitHub.
For instance, see "[Uploading project to GitHub from Visual Studio 2010](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5437010/uploading-project-to-github-from-visual-studio-2010)".

The `README.md` is the default file made by GitHub on the creation of a repo.
You should clone that repo locally, then create a solution in it, in order for your Visual Studio to work directly in the local working tree of that repo.

Comment: @VonC - Any suggestions for [this](http://stackoverflow.com/q/34201058/2404470) please?