# Syncing source code with Git source control provider and Visual studio

Tags: git, visual-studio, github, version-control, repository

This time, I need to work with Git with Visual studio and is my [first time](https://try.github.io) source control configuration, so please bear with me :)

**concept:**

https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B0_k0QpCVjHYZFFyRng4b2R5b2s/view?usp=sharing

**Aim:**

- Sync all developers code to a single repository using [Git](https://git-scm.com/) & it's [provider](https://gitscc.codeplex.com/) in [Visual studio](https://www.visualstudio.com/).
- Allow developers to check in from and push to this repository
- Revert back to the last working condition
- Other advantages of version control

**What is already done:**

Following [this](http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/7ca517/git-version-control-in-visual-studio-2015/) article, I have setup the **main** [git repository](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YPNze.png) location as:

[image: git repository]

> `\\192.168.3.46\operation\Automation\gittest`

The code repository will be handled on our local LAN only.

The project location is

> `C:\Users\zameer\Desktop\WebApplication1`

The initial commit is also [done successfully](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zrQCV.png).

[image: done successfully]

A blue lock symbol is [also showing](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Bc35I.png)

[image: also showing]

**Problem:**

The main repository (`\\192.168.3.46\operation\Automation\gittest`) is appearing to be [blank](https://i.stack.imgur.com/76Iha.png).

[image: blank]

We wanted to sync all code on this main location. What steps I'm missing?

Comment: I don't think it's a good practice to sync this way. git should be hosted by app that controls access to server ".git" folder otherwise you may have inconsistent state there.

Comment: @Vlad - Thanks a lot for investing your time!! Can you please teach me how to handle **"source control"** using git in visual studio?

Comment: I'm not using Git extension for VS so can't answer about it. I'm just pointing that you should use something like http://gitstack.com/ to host server instead of shared folder. (or https://bitbucket.org/ as external hosting service)

Comment: @Vlad, I am under the impression that git will handle file locking appropriately, so pushing / pulling should always be atomic actions, even on a shared folder.  Have you actually encountered this problem, or is this speculation?

Comment: @ChrisNielsen, locking should work on local computer but I'm not sure about shared folder behavior. I never used git with shared folder so this is just my assumption.

Answer (score 1):

I think are you sync'ing changesets to the 192.168.3.46 repository, but nothing is actually updating that repository's working directory.  If this is the case, then I would expect a ".git" subfolder to be the only item in the repository's folder.

This folder may be hidden by default.  Have you set your windows explorer to show hidden files and folders?

If you want to update the repository's working folder, you can use the standard git commands to do so.  This should not be necessary if all you want to do is push and pull changesets (but it would not hurt anything either).